# Explanations of an Android image build script

Tags: shell, partition, gpt

I was getting one program for partitioning SD card.I have given that script below:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
   echo "example usage: $0 /dev/sdc \$ANDROID_ROOT"
   exit 1
fi

DRIVE=$1
ANDROID_ROOT_DIR=$2

sudo umount ${DRIVE}*

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$DRIVE bs=1 count=1024
sudo sync
sudo parted $DRIVE mklabel gpt
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart boot fat32 1MB 9MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart system ext4 9MB 521MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart cache ext4 521MB 1033MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart userdata ext4 1033MB 2033MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart media fat32 2033MB 3033MB
sudo sync

sudo mkfs.ext4 ${DRIVE}2 -L system
sudo mkfs.ext4 ${DRIVE}3 -L cache
sudo mkfs.ext4 ${DRIVE}4 -L userdata
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 ${DRIVE}5 -n media
sudo sync

sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/device/ti/panda/xloader.bin of=$DRIVE bs=131072 seek=1
sudo sync
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/device/ti/panda/bootloader.bin of=$DRIVE bs=262144 seek=1
sudo sync
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/boot.img of=${DRIVE}1
sudo sync
${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.img ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.ext4.img
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.ext4.img of=${DRIVE}2
sudo sync
sudo e2label ${DRIVE}2 system
sudo sync
```

I know that while executing this .sh file, the content will be running on linux.
Even though I can understand the program, I am having doubt on one line:

```
 ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.img ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.ext4.img
```

Please anyone can explain what happens in this line?
there is no linux command, then how can it run without error?

And another doubt is:

This code `parted` `DRIVE` as 5 partition as boot, system, cache, userdata and media. But why does boot not created? that is, `{DRIVE}1` is not set know? Then where will be `xloader.bin, bootloader.bin and boot.img` all stored?

Answer (score 2):

This line instructs the shell, which runs the script, to start a binary called `simg2img` located in directory `${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/host/linux-x86/bin/` providing it with two parameters, `${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.img` and `${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.ext4.img`.

In fact, almost every line of your script are similar to this one, the only difference is that a `sudo` binary is started.

Comment: shall i know the work of simg2img?

Comment: According to search results provided by a major Internet search service, it's an utility to do something particularly useful with ROM images. But that is a completely different topic.

Comment: what will this command do in this code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to answer beyond "It will launch that binary". I would advise you to look for the documentation on this tool, it's definitely not something common in UNIX or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The command is `simg2img`. The rest is the path to the executable.